# How to configure Delay For First retry in Spring Retry Framework

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, exception, spring-retry

Im working on an application where im using spring @Retryable to perform retry operation for 3 times (By default retry count is 3). Below is my sample code

```
@Retryable(
        value= CustomException.class,
        backoff = @Backoff(
                delay = 5000,
                multiplier = 2,
                maxDelay = 20000
        )
) 
public void performRetry() throws CustomException {
    try {

        if(RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount()==0) { // retry count starts from 0.
            logger.info("Starting Retry attempts. Thread name {}. Giving delay of 3 seconds", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        boolean response = service.execute();  // calling main service

        // Rest of the code

    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Retry Count {} Error occurred {}", RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount(), e.getMessage());
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My query is that i want to introduce a delay of 3 seconds before doing first attempt (not first retry) i.e. calling my main service `service.execute();` for the first time.

Since in spring retry it immediately triggers the first attempt without any delay. So in my code before im calling my main service `service.execute();` for the first time im using `Thread.sleep(3000);`

Im using `RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount()` to get retry count. So if its 0 meaning first attempt, 1 means second attempt (first retry call) and 2 means third attempt (second retry call).

Is there any other way that i can give delay apart from using thread.sleep()?

Is there any way i can specify delay for the first retry in @Retryable annotation?

Waiting for an early response.

Answer (score 0):

> My query is that i want to introduce a delay of 3 seconds before doing first retry i.e. calling my main service service.execute(); for the first time.

The first **retry** is the second **call**.

There is no way to configure a delay for the first call; you would have to do that in your calling code.

Comment: Gary - So if(RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount()==0) is the only way to introduce delay in very first retry, right?

Comment: One more time; it is the first **attempt**, not the first **retry**; the count will be 0 on the first **attempt** and 1 on the first **retry**.

Comment: @GaryRussell  I have update my question as well i.e. when RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() value is 0 that will be the first attempt. When its value is 1 that is second attempt or first retry and when its value is 2 that is third attempt or second retry.

Comment: @GaryRussell is there any way that we can introduce delay in the first attempt apart from using thread.sleep() as mentioned in the code snippet above. or is there any way to configure delay for the first attempt in Retryable annotation itself or by using retry template?

Comment: No; there is not.